# why my react app prints the previous value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to get the current value of my selectbox but the function returns the previous value here is my code
import React from 'react';

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            vlaue: '',
            select: '',
        };
    }
    result = (e) => {
        this.setState({ vlaue: e.target.value, });
    };
    select = (event) => {
        this.setState({ select: event.target.value });
        console.log(this.state.select);
    };
    render () {
        return (
            <form>
                <label>your name</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.result} />
                <select value={this.state.select} onChange={this.select}>
                    <option value="JS">JS</option>
                    <option value="php">php</option>
                    <option value="python">python</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        )
    };
};
export default Form;
```

for example when I select js then select php the function return js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setState` is asynchronous and cannot expect the output in the next line of code.

Add the `console.log` inside the callback of `setState` like below to check the updated value:

```
  select = (event) => {
    this.setState({ select: event.target.value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.select);
    });
  };
```

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vlaue: "",
      select: ""
    };
  }
  result = (e) => {
    this.setState({ vlaue: e.target.value });
  };
  select = (event) => {
    this.setState({ select: event.target.value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.select);
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>your name</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.result} />
        <select value={this.state.select} onChange={this.select}>
          <option value="JS">JS</option>
          <option value="php">php</option>
          <option value="python">python</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It does that because state updates are asynchronous. You're doing a console.log before state update happens. Hence it prints the old value.

You can update your code to this to make it work:

```
printSelectedValue = () => {
    console.log(this.state.select);
}

select = (event) => {
    this.setState({ select: event.target.value }, this.printSelectedValue)
};
```

The second parameter of setState is a callback function which is called after state is updated.